# PHP Regex for a string with alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I tried and could not find an answer for this issue, so I'm asking this question.

I need to create a regex for password validation and it must have following conditions.

- At least one letter
- At least one number
- At least one special letter ~ ! ^ ( ) { } < > % @ # & * + = _ -
- Must not contain $ ` , . / \ ; : ' " |
- Must be between 8-40 characters
- No spaces

I have created following regex but it does not work properly.

```
preg_match('/[A-Za-z\d$!^(){}?\[\]<>~%@#&*+=_-]{8,40}$/', $newpassword)
```

Can somebody please help me to fix this regex properly?

Thanks.

Comment: There a ton of questions like yours, search a little and you will find the answer.

Comment: just don't i hate sites that tell me i can't use a particular password. yours is worse than most "hey use a special character, but not one of theses special characters(don't ask us why, we dont know)"

Comment: @nogad: I understand your point of view (as a user point of view), but for security purpose it's a necessity.

Comment: if you think that, you dont much about security

Comment: @nogad: feel free to choose `1234` as password.

Comment: how does forcing me not to use "$" increase security? it of course does the opposite. as does the ascii character range, the limit ..

Comment: @nogad: You are very interesting, do you have a blog about security or something related to suggest to increase our skills about this particular subject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go, using [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to verify your conditions:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~!^(){}<>%@#&*+=_-])[^\s$`,.\/\\;:'"|]{8,40}$
```

Let's break it down a little, because it's kinda nasty-looking:

- The `^` asserts that it's at the start of the string.
- The first lookahead, `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`, verifies that it contains at least one letter (upper or lower).
- The second, `(?=.*\d)`, verifies that it contains at least one digit.
- The third, `(?=.*[~!^(){}<>%@#&*+=_-])`, verifies that it contains at least one character from your special characters list.
- Finally, `[^\s$,.\/\\;:'"|]{8,40}$` verifies that the entire string is between 8 and 40 characters long, and contains no spaces or illegal characters by using an inverted character class.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/orMzlm/2)

Comment: Instead of using this negative lookahead `(?!.*[$\`,.\/\\;:'"|])`, you can use the character class that tests the length to limit the set of characters. `[a-zA-Z0-9~!^(){}<>%@#&*+=_-]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Good idea. Updated.

Comment: Be careful, `[^\s$`,.\/\\;:'"|]` doesn't prevent bytes outside the ascii range. As an example, an accented character like `é` will pass. *( but actually it isn't specified that accented characters are forbidden)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: OP requested ASCII range, so that's what I went with. If he needs Unicode, the pattern is reasonably simple to modify.

Comment: That's the problem with negated character classes. They are not bounded to the ascii range and can match anything outside this range.