# Regex for at least 3 (numbers and special characters) in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a password rule that needs to satisfy those condition below:

At least 2 out of the following:
- At least 1 lowercase character
- At least 1 uppercase character
- At least 2 (numbers AND special characters)

I build my regex like this below:

```
String oneLowercaseCharacter = ".*[a-z].*";
String oneUppercaseCharacter = ".*[A-Z].*";
String oneNumber = ".*\\d.*";
String oneSpecialCharacter = ".*[^\\`\\~\\<\\,\\>\\\"\\'\\}\\{\\]\\[\\|\\)\\(\\;\\&\\*\\$\\%\\#\\@\\!\\:\\.\\/\\?\\\\\\+\\=\\-\\_\\ ].*";
String threeNumbersAndCharacters = ".*[0-9\\^\\`\\~\\<\\,\\>\\\"\\'\\}\\{\\]\\[\\|\\)\\(\\;\\&\\*\\$\\%\\#\\@\\!\\:\\.\\/\\?\\\\\\+\\=\\-\\_\\ ].*[0-9\\^\\`\\~\\<\\,\\>\\\"\\'\\}\\{\\]\\[\\|\\)\\(\\;\\&\\*\\$\\%\\#\\@\\!\\:\\.\\/\\?\\\\\\+\\=\\-\\_\\ ].*[0-9\\^\\`\\~\\<\\,\\>\\\"\\'\\}\\{\\]\\[\\|\\)\\(\\;\\&\\*\\$\\%\\#\\@\\!\\:\\.\\/\\?\\\\\\+\\=\\-\\_\\ ].*";
```

And then I build the function like this below:

```
if ((Pattern.compile(oneLowercaseCharacter).matcher(s).find() && Pattern.compile(oneUppercaseCharacter).matcher(s).find())
                            || (Pattern.compile(oneLowercaseCharacter).matcher(s).find()
                                && Pattern.compile(oneSpecialCharacter).matcher(s).find()
                                && Pattern.compile(oneNumber).matcher(s).find()
                                && Pattern.compile(threeNumbersAndCharacters).matcher(s).find())
                            || (Pattern.compile(oneUppercaseCharacter).matcher(s).find()
                                && Pattern.compile(oneSpecialCharacter).matcher(s).find()
                                && Pattern.compile(oneNumber).matcher(s).find()
                                && Pattern.compile(threeNumbersAndCharacters).matcher(s).find())) {
//Do my stuff here
}
```

However, it does not work as expected. Not really sure why but if I test with different passwords, results show like this:

qwerty123 true (not expected)

qwerty!@# false

qwerty12. true

Qwerty123 true

Qwerty12. true

Anyone has any idea where I missed?

Note: I search around stackoverflow already and look elsewhere already so that I came up with the above code, however could not go further.

Comment: Why don't you just do three if cases. Add +1 to a variable if it matches.

Then if the variable has a number greater or equal to two; then it's valid?

You don't have to embed them all into one if case.

Comment: Except `[`, `]` and `-`, you don't need to escape "special characters" inside a character class. As an aside, if you don't care about the reason the input is valid or not, you can build a single pattern for all the rules. Search on SO to see how to do it, there's a ton of questions about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Regex for a string with alphanumeric and special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120488/php-regex-for-a-string-with-alphanumeric-and-special-characters)

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz nah I tried it already but it does not work. Probably different between java and php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
String oneSpecialCharacter = ".*[^\\`\\~\\<\\,\\>\\\"\\'\\}\\{\\]\\[\\|\\)\\(\\;\\&\\*\\$\\%\\#\\@\\!\\:\\.\\/\\?\\\\\\+\\=\\-\\_\\ ].*";
```

The character `^` has a special meaning ("not") when it is used in the first position inside `[]`.

This is why you need to escape it.

```
String oneSpecialCharacter = ".*[\\^\\`\\~\\<\\,\\>\\\"\\'\\}\\{\\]\\[\\|\\)\\(\\;\\&\\*\\$\\%\\#\\@\\!\\:\\.\\/\\?\\\\\\+\\=\\-\\_\\ ].*";
```

Now your result should looks like this:

```
qwerty123 -> false
qwerty!@# -> false 
qwerty12. -> true
Qwerty123 -> true
Qwerty12. -> true
```

---

Other examples that emphasize the meaning of `^`:

```
// the first character cannot be a
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("[^a]bc").matcher("abc").find());        // false

// the first character cannot be x, y or z, but it can be a
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("[^xyz]bc").matcher("abc").find());      // true

// the first character can be ^ or a
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("[\\^a]bc").matcher("abc").find());      // true

// the first character can be ^, x, y or z, but not a
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("[\\^xyz]bc").matcher("abc").find());    // false
```

Comment: Yeah it fix the issue. I didn't know about the meaning of the ^ character. Thanks a lot. Save me a day.

Comment: hmm that's interesting to know. Regex has to many ways to implement which makes me feel quite confuse every time I touch it.